# Enforcing a UNIQUE constraint between multiple tables when using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

When using Doctrine, how can I enforce a UNIQUE constraint for columns in two different tables?  For instance, `EntityB.some_property` must be unique for a given `EntityA.account_id`?  If I were to do this without using Doctrine, I would just duplicate `account_id` in `entity_b` and add the constraint.  With Doctrine, however, this will create an `Account` object in `EntityB` which is not desired.

```
entity_a
- id (PK)
- account_id (FK references account.id)

entity_b
- id (PK)
- primary_table_id (FK references entity_a.id)
- some_property (must be unique for a given account_id)
```

As seen below, my current approach just creates an Account entity in EntityB which I would rather not have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping https://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="NS\App\Entity\EntityA" table="entity_a">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one field="account" target-entity="Account" fetch="LAZY">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="account_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" nullable="false"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping https://www.doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="NS\App\Entity\EntityB" table="entity_b">
    <unique-constraints>
      <unique-constraint name="uniqueSomeProperty" columns="some_property, account_id_constraint"/>
    </unique-constraints>
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="someProperty" type="integer" column="some_property"/>
    <many-to-one field="accountConstraint" target-entity="Account" fetch="LAZY">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="account_id_constraint" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE" nullable="false"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: @programmer-man  I could show you using XML, but seems like everyone uses annotations.  I am not very good with annotations, but will try to reverse engineer what I've tried if you desire.

Comment: Doctrine using xml is fine :)

Comment: @programmer-man  Thanks.  When starting using Doctrine a month ago, I felt XML would be better, but am now starting to question that decision as I can't find as much XML oriented documentation and annotations are still kind of cryptic to me.

Comment: "With Doctrine, however, this will create an Account object in EntityB which is not desired." --- What if you assigned ang existing Account id to EntityB ?

Comment: @programmer-man  If possible, I think doing so would be great.  I expect I will have to do `$entityB->setAccountId(123);` if creating a new EntityB, but that is not a big issue.

Comment: Did you already do that? It's just a setter in your php file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190838/discussion-between-user1032531-and-programmer-man).